# How long does google Take to review my Developer Console Project?

Tags: google-drive-api

[Problem In This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYbkd.png)

I am facing this problem.I once submitted my app for verification but after 2 weeks a mail came from google that we cant Verify your App/Project.There i used the "Icon" thats why they told me to verify.

Then i again created a new project,Do the same but didnt upload any icon.Simply go thorough the process.They showed "Verification Not required
Google hasent reviewed ur app yet..."

Its been more than 10 days, they didnt even reviewed it.

In this time what do i need to do?Wait for them untill they review my app,will it be ok if they review my app.

Or do i need to go through the verification process?But i dont have any scopes that required verification.Please suggest me what should i do.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about how you have set up your project? What was your icon? What does your app do? Is it for the public? Is it possible to get a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Have you followed the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)? Have you set up your [OAuth Consent Screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent)?